# Phil, in his bedroom, texted Jane

Tags: meaning, adverbials, placement

a. In his bedroom, Phil texted Jane.

b. Phil, in his bedroom, texted Jane.

Wouldn't you say that there are three slightly different ways to understand these sentences?

1. Phil, who was in his bedroom, texted Jane.
2. Phil texted Jane when he was in his bedroom.
3. Phil texted Jane once he was in his bedroom.

Comment: I could not imagine anyone saying "Phil, in his bedroom, texted Jane. Therefore to speculate on the meaning of the sentence is pointless. " Phil phoned Jane from his office"

Comment: (a) _could_ imply 'once he had reached his bedroom', but that would entirely depend on context.